# springboot + tomcatのページ遷移ができない

Tags: spring-boot

現在、SpringBoot(バージョン2.1.4.RELEASE)でSpringSecurityを使用したwebアプリを作成しています。最初にログインページを表示し、認証成功時に2ページ目(top)に遷移する予定でした。

ローカルPCでtomcatとアプリを起動し、ブラウザからurlを入力するとログインページを表示し、ページ遷移します。その時のログが以下となります。

```
2019-09-04 13:36:45.344  INFO 216 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 15 ms
2019-09-04 13:36:50.503  INFO 216 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-09-04 13:36:50.950 DEBUG 216 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/xxx/", parameters={}
2019-09-04 13:36:50.956 DEBUG 216 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public java.lang.String yyy.TopController.index(org.springframework.ui.Model)
2019-09-04 13:36:50.992 DEBUG 216 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, image/apng, application/signed-exchange;v=b3, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2019-09-04 13:36:51.299 DEBUG 216 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

このアプリのwarを生成し、linuxサーバ(tomcat8を稼働)にデプロイし、実行するとログインページが表示されるので認証情報を入力しokをクリックすると、次ページに遷移せずにエラーを表示します。

サーバのアプリのログは以下のとおりです。

```
2019/09/04 04:24:00 INFO  [ajp-nio-8009-exec-1]  []  - Completed initialization in 28 ms
```

エラーメッセージは以下のとおりです。

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /xxx/login was not found on this server.
```

ローカルPCのようなGETのログが出力されず、次ページに遷移できません。
サーバにSpringBootのwebアプリをデプロイする際に必要な設定などがあれば教えていただきたいです。

ソースは以下のとおりとなります。
**<セキュリティアダプタ>**

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                // loginはアクセスを許可
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin() //
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("user").passwordParameter("password") // ログインページ
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/top", true) //認証成功時の遷移先ページ
                .failureUrl("?error")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout**"))       // ログアウト処理のパス
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                // ログアウト時に削除するクッキー名
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                // ログアウト時のセッション破棄を有効化
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                // セッションが無効な時の遷移先
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login");
        ;
      }
```

**<2ページ目>**

```
@Controller
public class TopController {
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "top";
    }
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ttp://localhost:8080/xxx/loginはログイン画面が表示されて、ttp://[サーバー]:8080/xxx/loginは404エラーになるってことですか？

Comment: 説明が足りなくてすいません。 ローカルPCで起動し、ttp://localhost:8080/xxx/loginでログインページを表示し、そこで認証入力すると次ページに遷移します。サーバで起動し、ttps://サーバ名/アプリ名/loginでログインページを表示しますが、そこで認証入力すると404エラーが表示されます。404エラーも2ページ目のtopがないということでなく、loginがないと言ってるので、認証処理も実行できてないのではと考えてます。

Comment: 「ttps://サーバ名/アプリ名/login」の「アプリ名」は「xxx」ではないんですか？

Comment: はい、ローカルpcでは「ttp://localhost:8080/xxx_web/login」でログインページを表示でき、サーバでは「ttps://サーバ名/yyy_web/login」でログインページを表示できます。サーバではhttpd.confの設定でアプリ名xxxをyyyに紐づけてます。

Comment: では、質問の本文の`The requested URL /xxx/login was not found on this server.`のメッセージの`xxx`は何ですか？

Comment: The requested URL /xxx_web/login was not found on this serverと表示されます

Comment: ttps://サーバ名/yyy_web/loginでログインページが表示されて、ログイン後に「 /xxx_web/login was not found」のメッセージが出力されるということはログイン後にコンテキストパスが変わったということになりますよね。そうであれば、設定（`httpd.conf`や`application.properties(yml)`）に問題があるのでは無いですかね？`xxx_web`が記述されているファイルがどこかにあり、その部分を見直すことで対応できそうに思います。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。apprication.propertiesでコンテキストパスやプロジェクトの設定でコンテキストルートにyyy_webを設定して試してるんですが、状況が変わりません。コンテキストが切り替わる点について、もう少しいろいろ試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

tomcatの設定でwarのフォルダ名と同じurlを設定して解決しました。